# read more doesn't display

Tags: read-more

I have been reading in the codex about the read more issue. It says when using the_excerpt, the character limit is 55 and then the *read more* should display which should look like this [...]

I am not seeing that in my excerpt. I have also tried several filters for testing.

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );

function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    global $post;
    return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read the full article&hellip;</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Neither of them work. I found that if I post the information in the content and use the more button which makes the `<!--more-->` then I see a link for the more button. I don't want to have to push that every time. So I looked up some posts on here but didn't find anything that helped. So I was wondering if I am doing something wrong in my query.

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'news', 'order' => 'ASC'));

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    global $more;
    $more = 0;
    ?><li><?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                ?><figure><?php the_post_thumbnail('news'); ?></figure>
            <?php } ?> 
            <!----------/ TITLE /---------->
            <em><?php the_title(); ?></em>
            <!----------/ DATE /---------->
            <strong><?php the_date(); ?></strong>
            <!----------/ PARAGRAPH /---------->
                <?php if( has_excerpt()){
                        the_excerpt();
                } else {
                        the_content('Read More'); 
                } ?>
            <!----------/ BUTTON /---------->
 </li>
 <?php
    endwhile;
    // Restore original Query & Post Data
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

All my research says that the filters should work or adding stuff into the content should work. Things like:

```
 the_content( 'Read More' );
```

Is there something I am missing? I want to get the excerpt working so that I can limit the word count and automatically insert the read more link.

Comment: Are you using the excerpt meta box? If you enter text in there, it will override the `<!--more-->` tag and the word trimming

Comment: Also, "read the full article" and similar are not added to custom excerpts using the meta box

Comment: I am using the excerpt box under the post box in the edit post page. all reading suggests that adding more than 55 words or even adding the filter will then add a link to read more. The codex says that the_excerpt() does not automatically add a read more link so you need to add the code for a button under the excerpt which I have done. I have added the filter to limit the words to 20 but when I paste more than 55 words in the excerpt box, the entire text shows and I can't see the button because it breaks layout and is hidden. This is a page template. Does it matter it's not the home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `if( has_excerpt())` return false that's way its return full content remove condition and only use `the_excerpt()` then it will work.

I have another solution that i use :)

```
$content = get_the_content();
$short_content = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $content), 0, 10));
echo $short_content;
```

this function returns 10 words of post. after echoing content you can add button code like

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >read more ...</a>
```

now you cant't use `<!--more-->`

Comment: I tried removing the conditional before posting and it still didn't work. I don't know what the issue is. Most everything the codex says does not work in this template. I am wondering if it is because I am running multiple custom loops in the site and the query doesn't know which query to filter or something. I tried your option 2 with the custom function and that seems to work good. So I am just going to use that. thank you for posting.